# VSTO add-in: Find Monitor where Outlook is displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Good day everyone.

All my users have 2 monitors. I have a VSTO Outlook add-in which is basically a ribbon button and a form. If my ribbon button is clicked, I create and display a new form. I don't want my form to be displayed on the same monitor where outlook is displayed. I want to open it on the other monitor. This what I usually do in normal winforms apps:

```
        Screen[] allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;            

        int i = allScreens.Count<Screen>();

        if (i > 1)
        {
            foreach (Screen s in allScreens)
            {
                if (s.DeviceName != Screen.FromControl(this).DeviceName)
                {
                    myForm.Location = s.WorkingArea.Location;
                    myForm.maximise = true;
                    myForm.Show();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this._outlookAuths.Show(this);
        }
```

But there is no 'this' pointer when working in the Ribbon class. I tried to get the monitor in which the Ribbon button is shown, but it is not part of the normal winforms button class. Tried to get my form's parent, which should be MS Outlook but that returns null. Just as a sidenote, CentreParent property on my form is also not working, but CentreParent is kind of the opposite of what I want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check and change the Screen in your Form, before it's shown.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Screen.FromHandle` instead. You can retrieve `HWND` of the Outlook windows by casting `Explorer` or `Inspector` OOM objects to the `IOleWindow` interface and calling `IOleWindow.GetWindow`.

Use `Application.ActiveWindow` / `ActiveExplorer` / `ActiveInspector` depending on your definition of "where Outlook is displayed".

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Only saw your reply now. I remember the spec changed shortly after I posted the question and they wanted my form to display on the same monitor as Outlook